# How to make WordPress use protocol indepentent upload files?

Tags: plugins, images, uploads, urls, media

I am using `FORCE_SSL_ADMIN` in `wp-config.php` so everytime I upload a new image and inserted into the post, it is using SSL version

e.g.

```
<img src="https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/test.png" ..
```

My blog is using HTTP in the public side, so how to make the upload path as rotocol independent, e.g.

```
<img src="//www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/test.png" ..
```

Comment: Here is a new solution. Good luck. https://wordpress.org/plugins/really-simple-ssl/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a function to remove the protocol and hook it to the attachment URL:

```
function wpse_79958_remove_protocol_from_attachment($url) {
    $url = str_replace(array('http:', 'https:'), '', $url);
    return $url;
}
add_filter( 'attachment_link', 'wpse_79958_remove_protocol_from_attachment' );
```

Also consider to use relative URLs for attachments by using WordPress builtin function `wp_make_link_relative`:

```
add_filter( 'attachment_link', 'wp_make_link_relative' );
```

Place this code to your `functions.php`. Not tested though.

**Update**: already tested

Comment: Thanks first, but the `attachment_link` link work only when there is a link point to the attachment, but I am referring to the direct image file.

Comment: If you are pointing to the file manually, so keep in mind preferred protocol yourselves.

Comment: Nope, I am saying you plugin will not work when I follow the steps: Add Media -> Select the image -> [In the Attachment Display Setting] -> Link To Media File. You plugin will only work if I select the "Link To Attachment Page"

Comment: I can not reproduce your situation. I've forced admin SSL on localhost, but I still have new uploads with `http` rather than `https`.  
Anyway, it's easy to remove the protocol from the URL manually. Also there is no straight hook for this.

Comment: This is not an answer actually. This should receive some attention as would be really useful.

Comment: @MultiformeIngegno, Do you have any useful idea or just nattering?